# How to use textView with Fragments Android/Java?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
public class YourComputerRig extends Fragment {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Create the text view
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(30);

            textView.setText("Passed in var: " + variable);

            // Set the text view as the activity layout
            setContentView(textView);
        }
```

`new TextView(this)` and `setContentView` are throwing errors... What would I use as the parameter instead of this? Or would it be better to not use a fragment for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

overriding `onCreateView`, that is called to have the fragment instantiate its user interface view.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    textView.setText("Passed in var: " + variable);
    return textView;
 }
```

Through `getView()` you can get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView. In your case it will return a `TextView`

Comment: He is in a fragment. You need getActivity() instead of this.

Comment: give me five mins, I was just editing it @ElDuderino, but thanks for the tip